# Dropzone file - how to retrieve file name property created by renameFilename

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I am using Dropzone.js for my image uploads. I can upload the images that are renamed from its original names. When I hover over the image thumbs, after the upload happened, I can see the renamed names. How can I retrieve these names. When I use "file.name" I get the name of the file before it was renamed. I am constructing a delete function using "removedfile" and that is the reason I would need this.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
init: function() 
  {
  this.on("removedfile", function(file) 
    { 
    var lot = $(file.previewElement).find('[data-dz-name]').text();
    alert(lot);
    });
  }
```